# InputStream doesn't read via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

I have two devices connected via Bluetooth. I want to send more String from a device to another but the method read() doesn't work correctly (only when I want to read the last String).

The strange thing is that, it works fine with:

```
inStream.read(keyRead);
outStream.write(answer.getBytes(charsetCod));
inStream.read(sizeRead);
inStream.read(messageRead);
inStream.read(timeSent);
```

But it doesn't work only when the application do:

```
int byteRead = inStream.read(alreadyReceived);
```

Someone could help me to understand why doesn't it read?
(Sorry for my bad english)

This is the code:

When I read from InputStream:

```
public void run(BluetoothDevice device)  {
    Log.i(TAG, "Sono nel run del ConnectedThread");
    dev_recipient = btAdapter.getName();    // se sto per leggere, il destinatario sono io
    dev_sender = device.getName();

    Log.i(TAG, "il mittente è: " + dev_sender);
    Log.i(TAG, "Il destinatario è " + dev_recipient);
    mac_sender = device.getAddress();
    mac_recipient = btAdapter.getAddress();

    byte[] keyRead = new byte[50];
    byte[] sizeRead = new byte[10];
    byte[] timeSent = new byte[100];
    byte[] alreadyReceived = new byte[500];
    String message;
    String sentTime;

    while (true) {                  // finchè è connesso
        try {
            messDB = new MessagesDatabase(context);
            messDB.getWritableDatabase();

            Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Ricevo la chiave del messaggio");
            inStream.read(keyRead);
            String keyS = new String(keyRead);
            int indkeyS = keyS.indexOf("#end", 0);
            String key = keyS.substring(0, indkeyS);
            Log.i(TAG, "Stringa chiave del messaggio: " + key);

            Log.i(TAG, "Controllo se ho già ricevuto il messaggio");

            if(messDB.existsMess(key)){
                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Il messaggio è già stato ricevuto");
                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Informa il mittente di non inviare");
                answer = "NO#end";
                outStream.write(answer.getBytes(charsetCod));
                outStream.flush();
                run(device);

            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Il messaggio non è stato mai ricevuto");
                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Informa il mittente di inviare");
                answer = "YES#end";
                outStream.write(answer.getBytes(charsetCod));
                outStream.flush();

                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Ricevi la grandezza del messaggio");
                inStream.read(sizeRead);
                String s =  new String(sizeRead);
                int ss = s.indexOf("#end", 0);
                Log.i(TAG, "indice di #end: " + ss);
                String sz = s.substring(0, ss);
                Log.i(TAG, sz);
                int size = Integer.parseInt(sz);
                Log.i(TAG, "La grandezza del messaggio è " + size);
                byte[] messageRead = new byte[size];


                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Ricevi il messaggio");
                inStream.read(messageRead);
                message = new String(messageRead);      // converte i bytes in String
                Log.i(TAG, "Ricevuto messaggio dall'inputStream: " + message);

                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: ottengo data e ora di ricezione messaggio");
                long receivedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");
                Date dt = new Date(receivedTime);
                String receivedTimeString = df.format(dt);
                Log.i(TAG, "Il messaggio è stato ricevuto alle " + receivedTimeString);

                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Ricevo ora e data di invio messaggio");
                inStream.read(timeSent);
                sentTime = new String(timeSent);
                int senInd = sentTime.indexOf("#end", 0);
                String sentTimeSender = sentTime.substring(0, senInd);
                Log.i(TAG, "Il messaggio è stato inviato il: " + sentTimeSender);

                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Ricevo gli already received");
                int byteRead = inStream.read(alreadyReceived);
                Log.i(TAG, "sono stati letti " + byteRead + " byte");
                String ar = new String(alreadyReceived);
                Log.i(TAG, ar);
                int arInd = ar.indexOf("#end", 0);
                String myAr = ar.substring(0, arInd);
                Log.i(TAG, myAr);
                String allReceived = myAr.concat(";mac_recipient");
                Log.i(TAG, "AlreadyReceived: " + allReceived);

                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Informo il mittente che ho ricevuto il messaggio");
                String answOk = "OK#end";
                outStream.write(answOk.getBytes(charsetCod));

                String path = saveMessageAsFile(key, message);

                Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Invio l'intent per mostrare all'utente il messaggio ricevuto");
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MESS_READ);
                intent.putExtra("key_mess", key);
                intent.putExtra("messRead", message);
                intent.putExtra("sender", dev_sender);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                Log.i(TAG, "Intent concluso");

                addMessageToDb(key, message, dev_sender, dev_recipient, receivedTimeString, sentTime, path, allReceived, size);

                read(device);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Disconnesso!", e);
            connectionLost();
            ManageConnections.this.start();     // riavvia la connessione
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

For writing:

```
public void write(final String key, final BluetoothDevice device) {
        dev_sender = btAdapter.getName();
        dev_recipient = device.getName();
        mac_sender = btAdapter.getAddress();
        mac_recipient = device.getAddress();

        final byte[] answerClient = new byte[10]; 
        final byte[] ricevuto = new byte[10];

        try {  
            final String keyy = key.concat("#end");
            final byte[] keyWrite = keyy.getBytes(charsetCod);
            outStream.write(keyWrite);        // invia la chiave del messaggio
            outStream.flush();
            Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: ho inviato la chiave del messaggio al destinatario, aspetto la risposta..");
            try {
                inStream.read(answerClient);
                final String answerC = new String(answerClient);
                Log.i(TAG, answerC);
                final int ansInd = answerC.indexOf("#end", 0);
                Log.i(TAG, "indice: " + ansInd);
                answer = answerC.substring(0, ansInd);
                Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: la risposta del dispositivo: " + answer);

                if (answer == "NO") {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Il messaggio è già stato ricevuto, non inviare");
                    aggiornaAlreadyReceived(device.getAddress(), key);

                }
                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Il messaggio non è stato ricevuto, invia..");
                    messDB = new MessagesDatabase(context);
                    messDB.getWritableDatabase();
                    final Messaggio m = messDB.getMessage(key);

                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Invio la grandezza del messaggio");
                    final int size = m.getSize();
                    Log.i(TAG, "La grandezza è " + size);
                    final String sizeString = String.valueOf(size);
                    final String ss = sizeString.concat("#end");
                    Log.i(TAG, ss);
                    final byte[] sizeByte = ss.getBytes(charsetCod);                        
                    outStream.write(sizeByte);
                    outStream.flush();


                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Invio il messaggio");
                    final byte[] message = m.getMessage().getBytes(charsetCod);
                    final long sentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    outStream.write(message);
                    outStream.flush();

                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Invio data e ora in cui il messaggio è stato mandato");                      
                    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");
                    final Date dt = new Date(sentTime);
                    final String sent = df.format(dt);
                    final String sentime = sent.concat("#end");
                    final byte[] sentTimeByte = sentime.getBytes(charsetCod);                      
                    outStream.write(sentTimeByte);
                    outStream.flush();

                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Invio gli already_received");
                    final String myAlRec = m.getAlreadyReceived();
                    Log.i(TAG, myAlRec);
                    final String myAlreadyRec = myAlRec.concat("#end");
                    Log.i(TAG, myAlreadyRec);
                    final byte[] allReceived = myAlreadyRec.getBytes(charsetCod);
                    outStream.write(allReceived);
                    outStream.flush();

                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Aspetto che il destinatario mi informi dell'arrivo del messaggio");
                    String ric = "";
                    inStream.read(ricevuto);
                    final String ricev = new String(ricevuto);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Il destinatario risponde con " + ricev);
                    final int ricInd = ricev.indexOf("#end", 0);
                    ric = ricev.substring(0, ricInd);
                    Log.i(TAG, ric);
                    if(ric == "OK") {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Il destinatario ha ricevuto il messaggio");
                        aggiornaAlreadyReceived(mac_recipient, key);
                    }
                    else Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Il messaggio non è stato ricevuto");

                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Invio l'intent per informare l'utente che il messaggio è stato inviato");
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MESS_WRITE);
                    intent.putExtra("key_mess", key);
                    intent.putExtra("recipient", dev_recipient);
                    intent.putExtra("ric", ric);
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Mittente: Intent concluso");

                }
            }
            catch (final Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Errore");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Eccezione durante la scrittura dell'id del messaggio", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NO_MESSAGE);
            intent.putExtra("key_mess", key);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please comment what changed your mind about the answer of the question? thank you

Comment: I think there are two way to resolve this problem.
First, I can use a single call for "sentTime" data and "AlreadyReceived" data. In this way it works fine but I can't understand why this change resolved this problem so I've decided to use ObjectInputStream that is a specialized InputStream and it is able to read generic Java objects and it's more simple to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class BlueTooth
{
    public String tag = "Bluetooth";
    public static final UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    public BluetoothAdapter adapter;
    public BluetoothDevice device = null;
    public BluetoothSocket socket = null;

    //public static final char ESC = (char) 27;
    //public static final char CR = (char) 13;
    //public static final char LF = (char) 10;

    public BlueTooth(String MAC)
    {
        this(MAC,null);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1)
    public BlueTooth(String MAC, byte[] pin)
    {
        try
        {
            adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            // wait for enable this is not very correct
            if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
                adapter.enable();
                SystemClock.sleep(5000);
                if (!adapter.isEnabled()) throw new IOException("Bluetooth is off");
            }

            if (!BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(MAC)) throw new Exception("Err MAC adress (" + MAC + ")");

            device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
            // this is only for testing purpouse i dont use this
            if (pin!=null)
                setPin(pin);
            // i have some trouble with my device on different OS                
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            else
                socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    public void setPin(byte[] pin)
    {
        try
        {
            Method setPin = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
            setPin.invoke(device, pin);
            Log.i("BlueTooth", "PIN is set: "+new String(pin));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable
    {
        disconnect();
        super.finalize();
    }

    // Android REfs recommend to cancel discover
    public boolean connect()
    {
        try
        {
            while (adapter.isDiscovering())
            {
                adapter.cancelDiscovery();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            socket.connect();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }

    // After write is good(only for shure for next write) to clear buffer with flush    
    public void write(byte[] in) throws Exception
    {
        socket.getOutputStream().write(in, 0, in.length);
        socket.getOutputStream().flush();
    }


    // Wait for incomming data
    // if is something in the buffer start count but max 3sec 
    // 3 sec is defined by my device vendor for reply
    //
    // after it we something on buffer.
    // you must realize the reading is on the fly
    // there for you must wait after read to next data sleep(1mxec)
    // until data are available
    // then return
    public byte[] read() throws Exception
    {

        int treshHold = 0;
        while (socket.getInputStream().available()==0 && treshHold<3000)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1);            
            treshHold++;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        baos.reset();

        while (socket.getInputStream().available() > 0)
        {            
            baos.write(socket.getInputStream().read());
            Thread.sleep(1);   
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();

    }

    // This is little low
    // after disconnect you must create 
    // new socket
    // so after disconnect you are not able to use connect
    // withous createRFcommSocket
    public void disconnect() throws Exception
    {
        if (socket != null) socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mertuarez, nice piece of work ;) Could you please add a bit of explanation. Especially the part you use Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I fully understand your code but got a couple of hints that could help.

Please check [Managing a Connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection) part. As you can see;

> You should use a *dedicated thread* for all stream reading and
>   writing. This is important because both *read(byte[])* and *write(byte[])*
>   methods are **blocking calls**. *read(byte[])* will block **until there is
>   *something* to read from the stream**. *write(byte[])* does not usually
>   block, but can block for flow control if the remote device is not
>   calling *read(byte[])* quickly enough and the intermediate buffers are
>   full. So, your main loop in the thread should be dedicated to reading
>   from the InputStream.

First for a better design you should use a dedicated thread for reading and one another for writing. You should separate the part you form your data, write it to OutputStream and read from InputStream.

When i started coding my *Reader Thread*, I tho *read(byte[])* method of InputStream will block execution until there are desired number of bytes. But it doesn't. I figured out that it does block until there is "something" to read from the stream (the part which i previously missed).

---

You have a byte array of size 500. What is the entry in log when you "can not" (in this case) read the stream in part:

```
int byteRead = inStream.read(alreadyReceived);
Log.i(TAG, "sono stati" + byteRead + " byte");
```

My point is: Consider your package is; 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09, you sent it via OutputStream write and flushed. You still might get **only a part of it** (even 1 byte -> 0x01) in one read() call, and get the rest of it (0x02 and the rest) in the next read() call. In this case `byteRead` will be equal to 1 and `alreadyReceived[0]` will be 0x01 and the other elements will be 0

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to say that I've used a different thread for reading and writing. I posted only the two functions (run and write).

The part of code is:
Log.i(TAG, "Destinatario: Ricevo gli already received");
int byteRead = inStream.read(alreadyReceived);
Log.i(TAG, "sono stati" + byteRead + " byte");

And the log print:
Destinatario: Ricevo gli already received.


And nothing else. It's blocking in inStream.read(alreadyReceived); as if there isn't something else to read,
but I really don't understand why.
Thank you for answer!

Comment: Are you sure there other bytes to read in InputStream ? I suggest you test it using a big size array and read() all data in one method call. You can also use InputStream.available() method but as the documentation states it's not very reliable. You can use it to check if any data available in stream checking if the return value is 0 or not. (As done in Mertuarez's code)

Comment: I've resolved! As you suggest me, I've used a single call for the "sentTime" data and "AlreadyReceived" data.
So, I've used a new String a = sentTime.concat(AlreadyReceived) and then inStream.read(a). In this way, it works fine. Thank you!